# why my logdiv is disappearing after clicking sign in button?

Tags: asp.net

i have a div logdiv which appears after clicking a button login for sign in..and there is a button named signin button in the div..when i click on the sign in button for sign in the page reloads and it disappears the logdiv whether the userid and password don't matched..i want to remain it untill the password and userid matched...

my logdiv portion

```
<div id="logdiv" runat="server">
       <p id="logidlabel">User ID</p>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="logintext" CssClass="logusertext"></asp:TextBox>
        <p id="logpasslabel">Password</p>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="logpasstext" CssClass="logpasstext"    TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="signin" CssClass="signinbt" Text="Sign in" OnClick="signin_Click"/>
        <asp:Label ID="errorsignin" runat="server" Visible="False" ></asp:Label>   
    </div>
```

my codebehind

```
protected void signin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT password from usertable where userid = " + "'" + logintext.Text.ToString() + "'", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    reader.Read();

    try
    {
        string password = reader["password"].ToString();
        string pass2 =logpasstext.Text.ToString();

        if (password == pass2)
            iframestyle.Attributes["src"] = "userpage.aspx";
        else
        {
            errorsignin.Visible = true;
            errorsignin.Text = "INVALID LOGIN";
            logdiv.Attributes["display"] = "block";
        }
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorsignin.Visible=true;
        errorsignin.Text = "INVALID LOGIN";
    }

}
```

i don't want to disappear the logdiv until the password and userid don't matched...i am getting the password and the userid from database..is database making the reload of the page???

Comment: though not the solution but why logpasstext.Text.ToString()? whats wrong with just logpasstext.Text

Comment: actually it doesn't matter i think..i have omitted this and it worked also

Comment: Oh boy! [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html), [passwords stored as plain text](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right)... Your site is just another security breach waiting to happen.

Comment: iframestyle?? What is it?? I guess its causing the problem.

Comment: when password matches pass2 it's ok..no problem there..i am redirecting it to userpage..but when it doesn't match the login div should stay..i couldn't do that though i am writing the logdiv.Attributs["display"]="block" becuase in my css it has display:none;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by fixing the most egregious error - the [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html) in your code. While we're at it, we'll check the result of the `Read()` call rather than relying on an exception to tell us there are no rows, and wrap the disposable objects in `using` blocks.

```
protected void signin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT password FROM usertable WHERE userid = @username", conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", logintext.Text);

        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                string password = reader.GetString(0);
                if (password == logpasstext.Text)
                {
                    iframestyle.Attributes["src"] = "userpage.aspx";
                }
                else
                {
                    errorsignin.Visible = true;
                    errorsignin.Text = "INVALID LOGIN";
                    logdiv.Attributes["style"] = "display:block;";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errorsignin.Visible = true;
                errorsignin.Text = "INVALID LOGIN";
                logdiv.Attributes["style"] = "display:block;";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To fix the immediate problem, you need to set the `style` attribute rather than the custom `display` attribute.

Now that we've got that out of the way, you need to reconsider your password storage strategy. Storing passwords in plain text is an incredibly bad idea. You should be storing salted hashes instead. Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right) for more information.

Finally, it looks like you need to get to grips with [Forms Authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240); I suspect your current implementation would allow an unauthenticated user to request `userpage.aspx` without having to log in first.

Comment: i applied this..but like my code it is updating that means the invalid login this text is showing but the logdiv is disapearing..i don't know why??

Comment: @setu: The `div` is disappearing because you're adding an attribute called `display` with a value of `block`. You need to set the `style` attribute with a value of `display:block;` instead. I've updated my answer.